# Fluid dynamics: valve and pressure drop

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I have a question regarding valves: Let's assume a district heating system where you want to control the mass flow in a sub-station with a valve.

1. Is (in normal cases) the diameter of the valve (full open) smaller than the diameter of the pipe that is going to the house (substation)?
2. Is this the reason, why a valve has a nominal pressure drop at full opening? Because when the diameter of the pipe and the valve would be equal, than the valve would have no pressure-drop when it is full open right?

Kind regards

Comment: There _is_ pressure drop in the pipe, so there is in the valve even if it has the same diameter. But it would probably be very small since the valve is very short.

Comment: This is more of an engineering question rather than a physics question, so I've voted it be closed. You might consider resubmitting it on [Engineering Stack Exchange](//engineering.stackexchange.com).